# Async functions - do I need .done()? What is its purpose?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

I have this in my React code:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._getAuthCookie().done();
}

async _getAuthCookie() {
//...
```

I copied the structure from elsewhere, but I'm wondering if the `.done()` is necessary, and if so, why?

Comment: [`done` should be a property of the iterator](http://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-arrows-IteratorBindingInitialization), not a function according to the spec.

Comment: What promise implementation are you using? What do you think `done()` does? If you don't know, then you probably should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

ES2016+ async/await internally are implemented as ES Promises.

`.done()` is not (thanks to GregL) a part of a Promise interface, which means that it's likely to fail, unless a polyfill that implements `.done()` is used.

In the promises implementations that provide `.done()` it accepts a function as its argument that will be invoked when a promise is resolved, eg: `something.done(function() { console.log("I'm done"); });`

In this case it does nothing useful (since you don't pass any callback to it) and can be removed.

Comment: Isn't it `.then()`, instead of `.done()`, on Promises? See [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/prototype#Methods).

Comment: @GregL oh gosh, sure.

Comment: In the case of [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) (the real one, not Angular-$q), `done()` actually does something useful (about unhandled rejections), but I don't think this was meant here.